# How to put a complete dark theme into my UWP?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, themes

I'm trying to made an UWP app that can change of theme. I'm using the instruction `RequestedTheme = ElementTheme.Dark;`, but this only changes the "basic items", I'm talking about the background and text.
The textBox, the ContentDialog and others aren't into the dark mode.
I'd like to find a way to "dark" ALL the items into the app, not only the text and background.
Hope there's any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set theme on the application and element level.

If you want to set it on application level, it must be done when the app is started (in `App.xaml.cs` constructor). This setting cannot be changed at runtime.

To switch theme at runtime, you can utilize the `RequestedTheme` property on a control. This applies the theme to the control and its children in the visual hierarchy. This can be switched any time at runtime. To make the selected theme apply to the whole application, you need to set it on a top-level visual element - ideally the root element of the window:

```
var root = (FrameworkElement)Window.Current.Content;
root.RequestedTheme = ElementTheme.Dark;
```

Usually, the window's content is a `Frame` but, more generally it can be an arbitrary `FrameworkElement`.

Comment: Thanks! So, doing this, I cannot change it anymore... Thanks, I'll try. The idea was a "change theme button", but if I cannot, this works. Really thanks!

Comment: @Tupi the two lines of code at the end of my answer is for most purposes the same thing as changing the application-wide setting and it only doesn't apply to `MessageDialog`, so you can use that for your change theme button :-) - most apps which offer theme change at runtime do it this way

Comment: Hey! I've done this, but it only changes the background and the text (like the this.themeRequest). The contentDialog, for example, isn't changing. :(

Comment: you are right, `ContentDialog` is another of the thing that don't change automatically. To make sure everything is adjusted, make sure to set Application.RequestedTheme accordingly during the next startup. You can also manually set `RequestedTheme` for the elements which don't change automatically, so you can have better experience after the runtime change without having to restart :-)\

Comment: Thanks, boy! I'll do this, I'll change the `RequestedTheme` of this thinks that don't change. Really thanks!